# Password Authentication Issue SSH - Cannot disable

Tags: ssh, authentication, sshd

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
Set up SSH as I have done for years.

In /etc/ssh/ssh_config changed:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Restarted the service `systemctl restart sshd`

I can still log in by Password.

It seems /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf
contains a line `PasswordAuthenticaion yes`   which overrides ssh_config

To my way of thinking this is a security flaw introduced by Ubuntu in this release as it breaks years of tradition and standard practice where disabling password authentication in sshd_config has worked. I can imagine a releaseupdate potentially changing a setting or a standard config being thrown in place by scripts and getting subverted by this change.

Is there a reason for this change or is it a mistake in this release?

Thanks

Comment: `cloud-init` in the filename suggests that this may be an automatically-provisioned system like a VM or VPS, not a manual bare-metal install. If true, look to the provisioner.